# How to differentiate items values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, diff

I have this DataFrame

| index | N1 | N2 | N3 | N4 | N5 | time | CountN1 | CountN2 | CountN3 | CountN4 | CountN5 | resultN1 | resultN2 | resultN3 | resultN4 | resultN5 | RhoN1 | RhoN2 | RhoN3 | RhoN4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | chocolate | sugar | milk | eggs | flour | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.4142135623730951 | 1.4142135623730951 | 1.4142135623730951 | 1.4142135623730951 |
| 1 | bread | pizza | soda | water | batteries | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 |
| 2 | plant | tea | coffe | chorizo | pasta | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 3.1622776601683795 | 3.1622776601683795 | 3.1622776601683795 | 3.1622776601683795 |
| 3 | tomatoes | bread | cheese | pasta | soda | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 4.123105625617661 | 4.898979485566356 | 4.123105625617661 | 4.58257569495584 |
| 4 | Garlic | Onion | Rice | Bacon | Water | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 3.0 | 5.0990195135927845 | 5.0990195135927845 | 5.0990195135927845 | 5.0990195135927845 |

So N columns are items bought by customers, time is a continuous ranked time, CountN columns are cumulative counting items bought, resultN are time intervals between the same items from a customer to another, and RhoN columns are angles.

All I want is columns RhoN1_diff, RhoN2_diff, RhoN3_diff, RhoN4_diff,RhoN5_diff that give the diff of Rho columns per items along the daframe. For example, bread have rho values 2.23606797749979 at time 2 and 4.898979485566356 at time 4. The trick is items like bread can be in any N columns per appear only once in a row.

Believe me, chat gpt is not ready to replace us.

If you need any more details, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Am I getting you right, that the issue is - 'bread' is in N1 at index 1 and N2 at index 3? Also, would you like to collect these  values and name the columns like "bread_n" and "bread_diff" ?

Comment: One more additional clarification:
if bread count is not continuous across time, would you treat this as diff -10 and diff +11?

|bread_n|time|
|--|--|
|10|2|
|NA|3|
|11|4|

Comment: Hi Dude, No i just wanted to create diff columns in respect to time to differente rho values per time along the dataframe. But i found the way to solve the problem, i will post it. thanks for your time man. Let me know if you would need more details or explantions about the answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

After hours i finally found the answer. If that could spare some time to anyone facing a similar issue. here is the code:

```
# Melt the DataFrame to create a more convenient format
melted_df = pd.melt(new_df, id_vars=['time'], value_vars=['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5'], var_name='N', value_name='item')

# Merge the melted DataFrame with the corresponding RhoN columns
rho_columns = ['time', 'RhoN1', 'RhoN2', 'RhoN3', 'RhoN4', 'RhoN5']
melted_df = melted_df.merge(new_df[rho_columns], on='time')

# Create a new column containing the corresponding RhoN values for each item
melted_df['RhoN'] = melted_df.apply(lambda x: x[f"RhoN{x['N'][1:]}"], axis=1)

# Drop unnecessary columns
melted_df.drop(columns=['RhoN1', 'RhoN2', 'RhoN3', 'RhoN4', 'RhoN5'], inplace=True)

# Calculate the RhoN differences
melted_df = melted_df.sort_values(['item', 'time'])
melted_df['RhoN_diff'] = melted_df.groupby('item')['RhoN'].diff()

# Pivot the table back to the original format
pivoted_df = melted_df.pivot_table(index='time', columns='N', values='RhoN_diff', aggfunc='first')
pivoted_df.columns = [f'Rho{col}_diff' for col in pivoted_df.columns]

# Fill NaN values with zeros
pivoted_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Set the index of both DataFrames to be the `time` column
new_df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
pivoted_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
pivoted_df.set_index('time', inplace=True)


# Merge the pivoted table back with the original DataFrame using an 'outer' merge
final_df = new_df.merge(pivoted_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
# Reset the index of the final DataFrame
final_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Fill NaN values with zeros in the final DataFrame
final_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

If you need more details or explanations, please let me know.